# jQuery to wrap certain word in <strong> tag

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to use jQuery to search for all instances of the word "contracting" and wrap it in

```
<strong>
```

tag. Is there any way to do this using jQuery? The end result I'd be looking for is

```
<strong>contracting</strong>.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/contracting/g, "<strong>contracting</strong>"));
});​
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/QQAPK/)**

Comment: To change all the occurances in the page (not just those inside <p> tags) you can write `var replace_str = $('body').html().replace(/contracting/g, '<strong>contracting</strong>'); $('body').html(replace_str);`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have your content you are replacing surrounded by something `<span>` `<div>` with an ID for this to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">Contracting</div>​
```

JS:

```
content=document.getElementById("content");

​content.innerHTML=content.innerHTML.replace(/contracting/gi,"<strong>$&</strong>");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jwTz8/

The JSfiddle works but the font doesn't change for me, you may have to inspect the element (right click Contracting, inspect element) to see the strong tags are there.

Comment: I don't think this answers the actual question: it will not change all instances of the word "contracting" and also it doesn't use jQuery

Comment: The other suggestions here don't change every instance either, but I will edit to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var yourElement = $("#your-element-selector");

yourElement.html(yourElement.html().replace("yourword", "<strong>yourword</strong>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){

$("p").each(function() {

var self = $(this);

self.html(self.html().replace(/contracting/gi, "<strong>$&</strong>"));

})

})()
```

;